# Passing PHP variables into my Livewire action parameter crashes my action method- blade template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, livewires

Passing PHP variables into my Livewire action parameter crashes it.

```
 @php {{ $tel = 'telephone'; }} @endphp

<button wire:click="sortBy({{$tel}})">
    Add Todo
</button>
```

This is the error message in my console:

```
VM527:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: telephone is not defined
    at eval (eval at value (wire-directives.js:93:24), <anonymous>:8:16)
    at Directive.value (wire-directives.js:100:22)
    at Directive.get (wire-directives.js:58:33)
    at node_initializer.js:209:42
    at Component.value (index.js:582:9)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (node_initializer.js:201:23)
```

When I pass a simple string into the same method it works i.e

```
<button wire:click="sortBy('telephone')">
    Add Todo
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already answered your own question. You're passing a string but you're not quoting it, so it's not evaluated as one.

```html
@php {{ $tel = 'telephone'; }} @endphp

<button wire:click="sortBy('{{$tel}}')">
    Add Todo
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks- you are right. but if you look at this link: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/actions -- they do not put quotes:-<button wire:click="addTodo({{ $todo->id }}, '{{ $todo->name }}')">

Comment: @PaulKendal if you pay attention, they actually do. They do it around the name variable, just not around the ID. This is because the ID is an integer, which can be passed freely without quotes.